# Awk in Python's subprocess giving Invalid Expressions "'" error

Tags: python, bash, awk, subprocess, ls

I am trying to read the filename and filestamp for the most recent files of each of the two naming schemes as seen in the code. I have the following code, roughly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import string, subprocess, sys, os
mypath = "/path/to/file"


my_cmd = (["ls -lt --full-time " + mypath + "*DAI*.txt",
          "ls -lt --full-time " + mypath + "*CA*.txt"]
         )
getmostrecent_cmd = "head -n 1"
getcols_cmd = "awk '{ print $6, $7, $9 }'"

for cmd in my_cmd:
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p2 = subprocess.Popen(getmostrecent_cmd.split(), stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p3 = subprocess.Popen(getcols_cmd.split(), stdin=p2.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = p3.communicate()[0]

    print output
```

which give me the following error(s):

```
ls: cannot access /path/to/file/*DAI*.txt: No such file or directory
awk: '{
awk: ^ invalid char ''' in expression

ls: cannot access /path/to/file/*CA*.txt: No such file or directory
awk: '{
awk: ^ invalid char ''' in expression
```

But:

1. I can use "**ls -lt --full-time /path/to/file/*DAI*.txt**" and get a result in the terminal. Why is it causing an issue with the same path?
2. The awk command, when put in to subprocess directly, works fine; E.g. **subprocess.Popen(["awk", ....], stdin=...., stdout=....)** worked okay. But now I am getting an issue with the single quote. I tried triple quoting the string and escaping the single-quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can use **"ls -lt --full-time /path/to/file/*DAI*.txt"** and get a
>   result in the terminal. Why is it causing an issue with the same path?

Glob expansion is performed by the shell. By default, shell is not involved in starting a new subprocess via `Popen()`. To this end you must pass the `shell=True` argument to it:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
#                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^
```

> The awk command, when put in to subprocess directly, works fine; E.g.
>   **subprocess.Popen(["awk", ....], stdin=...., stdout=....)** worked okay. But now I am getting an issue with the single quote. I tried
>   triple quoting the string and escaping the single-quote.

On the shell command line the single quotes in **`awk '{ print $6, $7, $9 }'`** are needed to make the string **`{ print $6, $7, $9 }`** treated as a single argument (as well as to prevent the variable expansion). The single quotes are removed by the shell, and `awk` only sees the string **`{ print $6, $7, $9 }`**. Since `Popen()` by default doesn't involve shell when executing the subprocess command and passes the arguments to the command verbatim, you don't need the single quotes:

```
subprocess.Popen(["awk", "{ print $6, $7, $9 }"], stdin=...., stdout=....)
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Your asnwer to 2 helped a lot. For 1, I was not supposed to use shell=True. My workaround was to ls out the full path and then grep for DAI and CA.